# Get out of a void method?

Tags: c#, coding-style

I have this method (modified code) :

```
public static void PublishXmlForCustomTypes(MyOwnClass DefaultOutputInformation)
{
    if (DefaultOutputInformation != null)
    {
        ///lot of code
    }
}
```

and my whole code was inside the if statement and after thinking about it, I changed to this :

```
public static void PublishXmlForCustomTypes(MyOwnClass DefaultOutputInformation)
{
    if (DefaultOutputInformation == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    ///lot of code
}
```

As far as I tested it, it seems to be strictly equivalent but is that really the case ?
I mean, the "return" statement get us out of the method right ?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This is strictly equivalent and the second version is the way to go :)

Comment: Isn't there an hidden case where this won't be equivalent ?

Comment: agreed, and upvoting.  Its easier on yourself and others who will later maintain it, if the scope of your IF block is as small as possible, even though functionally it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @Jérémy Talio: No, there isn't.

Comment: No, there are absolutely no situation where it will be different.

Comment: Upvoters - I can't see how this is the *right* answer. If #2 is the 'way to go' why is that?

Comment: The question was about "is that equivalent ?" and it is, but the 2nd solution is REALLY more elegant, that's all...

Answer (score 11):

Yes, that's absolutely fine.

Some people dogmatically stick to "one exit point per method" - which was appropriate when it was relatively tricky to make sure you always did the right amount of clean-up at the end of a function in C, for example... but it's not really necessary in C#.

Personally I think it's appropriate to return as soon as you know that you've done all the work you really want to in a method. Use `try/finally` or `using` statements to perform any extra "clean up however I exit" work.

Comment: I have come up against one-exit-point-per-method advocates. I understand their motive, but it can result in some seriously ugly code.

Comment: I was one of the dogmatic people until now, was a matter of habit I suppose.

Comment: @ThePower habit is something that comes naturally to us all. Kudos to you for breaking it ;-)

Comment: @ColinE it comes from my placement year working with only C developers whilst working in both embedded C and C# winforms. It's something that's just stuck with me since.

Answer (score 6):

yes `return` gets you out of the method; if you have a `finally` block and you call return from the `try` block, the `finally` block is executed anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the *return* statement ends the method.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the return will exit you out of the code.  It's generally good practice as the very first step in a function to verify that the parameters that were passed in are what you think they are and exit (via the return or throwing an exception) so that you don't do any unnecessary processing only to have to abort later in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your assumptions is correct.

For some background, learn about [duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_Laws).

Comment: Of all the sites you choose Wikipedia.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: Tomorrow this answer will be useful :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is exactly the same, you can read the MSDN documentation about the keyword return to fully understand how it works : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx

As to decide which way is better : both are good, but the second version makes it more readable because then your whole code isn't inside an if block. This way, you can see what the condition does really easily instead of reading the whole code of the method.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the `return` gets you out of the method, so it is equivalent to the first way you used. Which way is better depends on your code, although generally I would prefer the second version.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the revised code, the second one is the way to go.  While being functionally equivalent, think about the case where you passed in 4 different variables to a function that you want to check. Instead of having a do a nasty 4 level if statement with {'s everywhere, the second method allows you to clean up the appearance of the code and not add unnecessary levels of brackets.  If you're writing in C/C++, you can even make this a macro such as VERYIFY_NOT_NULL(x) and make the code nice and neat.

Readable/maintainable code trumps nano-seconds of performance 99% of the time.